# Is anti-glare 'computer' glasses effective at relieving eye-strain?

Tags: medical-science, ophthalmology

Does anti glare really works? Got many suggestions from fellow friends who practice medicine

1. Dont use them if you are not experiencing any strain
2. Use them it will be helpful to reduce strain
3. It will affect the eye moment
4. Dont use them just rest your eyes for a while. See the sky for a minute( I know this is true)

I found some page in internet which are contradictory to one another

Source : [LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/5980509/do-computer-glasses-really-work)

> First: If It Ain't Broke, Don't Fix It
>
> If you aren't experiencing any eye problems, you can just stop here.
>   Specially-coated and/or computer eyeglasses won't do anything for you
>   (other than geekify your look). In fact, they could be a hindrance.
>   Dr. Robert Noecker, an ophthalmologist and Director of Glaucoma for
>   Opthalmic Consultants of Connecticut, notes that:P
>
> Computer eyewear does not necessarily prevent eye strain in an already
>   optimized environment. Also, the range that the eyes can sweep from
>   one side to the other is maximized without any eyewear. The frame
>   edges limit this range of motion and may actually hinder people more
>   who are not getting much benefit from wearing the glasses. Also
>   eyeglasses get smudges which can interfere with vision as well

Source: [Wisegeek](http://www.wisegeek.org/do-i-need-anti-glare-glasses.htm)

> Eye strain is characterized by blurred vision, burning eyes, headache,
>   and tired eyes. If you are experiencing any of these symptoms while
>   using the computer, anti-glare glasses may be a wise buy for you. Even
>   if you are not a regular computer user, your eyes may benefit from
>   anti-glare glasses. In addition to being affected by the glare from
>   your computer screen, your eyes can be come strained from being in a
>   room with poor lighting. Anti-glare glasses can also be beneficial for
>   this type of situation, as they help reduce the strain on your eyes.
>
> Anti-glare glasses help reduce the amount of strain your eyes feel by
>   reducing the convergence of your eyes and by helping to reposition
>   your eyes to a more comfortable position. This reduces the strain
>   placed on the muscles in your eyes, as well as the tension your eyes
>   experience. In addition, anti-glare glasses help reduce the amount of
>   ultraviolet radiation that reaches your eyes, and they do not magnify
>   the light like traditional eyeglasses do.

Other sources:
[arstechnica](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2009/10/leveling-up-your-eyesight-with-gaming-glasses-ars-explores/)
[cbetternow](http://www.cbetternow.com/are-anti-reflective-anti-glare-lenses-worth-the-cost-t37.html)

Comment: Please use standard English and be specific about the claim you're skeptical of.

Comment: Can you please link to a notable example of such a claim. It isn't clear whether you are asking "Does anti-glare glass prevent glare?" or "Does anti-glare glass prevent eye-strain?". Or wait, do you mean *glasses*? In which case Rob's suggestion of a duplicate makes sense!

Comment: Sorry I was in mobile application when posting

Comment: Once you clarified as "glasses" not "glass", it was clearly a duplicate as discovered by Rob. Closed.